TenantDiscoveryFailed (0x300) using Custom URI to connect to AVD
When trying to connect to an application group (RemoteApp), using Uniform Resource Identifier schemes with the Remote Desktop client for Azure Virtual Desktop (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/uri-scheme) it gives the error:
"We failed to fetch the subscription information from https://rdweb.wvd.microsoft.com/api/arm/feeddiscovery [..]".
Error Symbolic: TenandDiscovery
FailedError code: 0x300
Formatted string:
ms-avd:connect?workspaceId=WORKSPACE_ID&resourceid=APPLICATION_GROUP_ID&username=UPN&version=0
It does work if I subscribe and start the app manually from the remote desktop app. It also work if one starts the application from the Start menu.
Has anyone been able to make this work?

The ResourceId should be the ObjectID of the application within the ApplicationGroup!
I was unable to find this ObjectID using the CLI, but I used a workaround:
Subscribe manually, and navigate to:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\rdclientwpf\

You will find a remote desktop shortcut to your application. That is the GUID that should be used for the resourceid parameter. This is the object ID of the application within the application group.
